# Login form using database information Delphi

Tags: delphi

So I'm using this:

```
procedure TfrmLogin.btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Result:Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  dbMarks.tblMarks.First;
  while not dbMarks.tblMarks.Eof do begin
    if dbMarks.tblMarks.FieldByName('Username').AsString = edtUsername.Text then begin
      Result := dbMarks.tblMarks.FieldByName('Password').AsString = edtPassword.Text;
      Exit;
    end;
    dbMarks.tblMarks.Next;
  end;
end;
```

I want to get usernames and passwords from my database then verify if the info entered matches that of the database. If i execute this code I keep getting: 'tblMarks: Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset'

How do I verify all of this without using a function?

Comment: You either need to set Result as a global variable or move all the block of code of this procedure to a function that return the boolean value you want.

Comment: Don't forget that it is a security risk to store your passwords in plain text. At the very least, hash them.

Comment: What do you mean by *"How do I verify all of this without using a function"*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure that your dataset is actually `Active`. You can't perform operations on a closed one. Set the dataset property `Active := True` first.

Answer (score 3):

If tblMarks is a TAdoTable, which it seems from a comment you removed that it is, or other TAdoxxx dataset, it is a lot quicker and more efficient to use its Locate method than to use a while loop to loop through the dataset looking for the username & password.  Try something like

```
[...]
begin

  if not dbMarks.tblMarks.Active then
    dbMarks.tblMarks.Open;
  Result := dbMarks.tblMarks.Locate('UserName', edtUsername.Text,   [loCaseInsensitive]);

  Result := Result and (edtPassword.Text = dbMarks.tblMarks.FieldByName('Password').AsString);

  if Result then begin
     // do whatever to log in the user, etc
  end;
[etc]
```

Btw, it's a beginner's mistake to put code like this in a ButtonClick handler.  It is better for the ButtonClick handler to call a function which performs the actual check:

```
function TfrmLogin.LogIn(const UserName, Password : String) : Boolean;
begin
  if not dbMarks.tblMarks.Active then
    dbMarks.tblMarks.Open;
  Result := dbMarks.tblMarks.Locate('UserName', edtUsername.Text,   [loCaseInsensitive]);
  Result := Result and (edtPassword.Text = dbMarks.tblMarks.FieldByName('Password').AsString);
end;
```

Note that in a function, the identifier Result is an alias for the function's name, so it's best to get out of the habit of using Result as the name of a variable elsewhere, it will likely lead to confusion.